# How to return one out of multiple values from a single C++ return statement?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, return, boolean-logic

```
return a or b or c or d;
```

That statement returns either `true` or `false` in C++, and I know the reason for this.

But I need a workaround so that I can **return the first *non-zero* value** via that return statement (or something similar) *like it happens in Python*.

I am not looking for conditional statements as it looks untidy [sometimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657965/hackerrank-save-the-prisoner?noredirect=1#comment7517434_3657997).

Basically, can the following code be shortened via a macro or something else?

```
int fun(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return a ? a : b ? b : c ? c : d;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write the function like this:

```
int fun(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a) return a;
    else if (b) return b;
    else if (c) return c;
    return d;
}
```

It is clean and short. I could stop here, but lets explore what can be done...

There exists an algorithm that already almost does what you want. A slight modification of the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61609681/4117728):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
T first_non_zero_or_zero(const std::initializer_list<T>& args)
{
    auto it = std::find_if_not(args.begin(),args.end(),[](auto v){ return v==0;});    
    return (it != args.end()) ? *it : 0;
}
```

The drawback of using a function for boolean expressions is no short-cuirciting. If you call the function via:

```
auto x = first_non_zero_or_zero( { foo(), expensive_function() });
```

Then `expensive_function` must be called, no matter what `foo` returns. The way to restore the ability to short-circuit is to pass callables instead, that would be

```
template <typename F>
auto first_non_zero_or_zero(F f){ return f();}

template <typename First,typename...F>
auto first_non_zero_or_zero(First f,F... others){    
    if (auto temp = f()) return temp;
    return first_non_zero_or_zero(others...);
}

int foo(){ return 0;}
int expensive_function(){ return 42;}

int main()
{
    std::cout << first_non_zero_or_zero(foo,expensive_function);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this will make calls unnecessarily verbose when called with simple `int`s, as you need to wrap them in a callable:

```
int fun(int a,int b,int c) {
    first_non_zero( [](){ return a;},
                    [](){ return b;},
                    [](){ return c;})
}
```

Conclusion: Don't make things more complicated than necessary. Functions should do one thing. The one thing your `fun` does is to return the first non-zero of 4 integers and a `if-else` is the most simple way to get that done.

Comment: My main aim does not revolve around `fun`, that was just a minimal reproducible example. What I wanted was a generic one-liner way to mimic that Python behaviour :p But I like the deep concepts covered in this answer.

Comment: @ArdentCoder as I said before, C++ is not Python. Lot can be learned by comparing two lanugages and try to see if what can be done in one can also be done in the other, but usually what is idiomatic in one can be crap in the other. Also one-liners arent always the most readable. Anyhow, I had my fun with exploring the issue, but imho the conclusion is as important as the rest of the anwer

Comment: Haha me too, it was fascinating how such a simple problem can make us explore many things ;)

Comment: Are you online? I have a doubt

Answer (score 4):

The task can be accomplished by using the necessary function in the return statement.

For example, instead of a macro, I used a **templated function which accepts the parameters in [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)**:

```
template <typename T>
T OR(const std::initializer_list<T>& args)
{
    for (const T& arg : args)
        if (arg)
            return arg;
    return T{};
}
```

It can be used as follows for the given problem:

```
return OR({a, b, c, d});
```

The problem in that link can also be solved in this way:

```
return OR({(m + s - 1) % n, n});
```

Note that it depends on the implicit boolean conversion of a given type `T`. So, for example, [an empty `std::string` is not `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530868/why-is-an-empty-string-literal-treated-as-true). Also, a user-defined type should have `operator bool() const` in order to comply with this workaround.

*P.S. While I was trying to ask my mistake in a variadic template solution in the question, I discovered this solution myself :P*

**Note:**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61611112/10251345) answer to know the limitations of this way when working with more complex designs.

Comment: if I understand OP correctly they insist on a one-liner. Your answer just shifts the code from `fun` to a different function. Nevertheless, I agree that this is the way to go

Comment: oh, you are the OP ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 But I'm not ticking my solution, maybe you could show me a better way like I was trying to do with variadic templates. Perhaps something which would also work with heterogeneous parameters.

Comment: `initializer_list` seems better IMO, variadic method would require to return one unique type (`std::common_type`?) anyway.

Comment: tbh I would actually prefer `if (a) return a; if (b) return b; ...etc..` in `fun` instead of a helper. Trying to mimic python in c++ isnt the best motivation to write clean code. At least you should give the function a better name, perhaps `first_non_zero`

Comment: also note that once you write a function you loose the ability to short-circuit.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Isn't the function mimicking short-circuit when it returns at the first non-zero value? Or are you referring to a short-circuit which I don't know yet, lol I'm not a very advanced C++ programmer.

Comment: @Jarod42 I would still like to see that kind of a solution to make the code more generic

Comment: suppose you call `OR` not with `int`s but with `OR({ some_function(),some_other_function()})` then both functions must be called so `OR` can be called. If you write `int temp = some_function(); if (temp) return temp; temp = some_other_function(); if (temp) return temp;` then in case `some_function` returns non-zero the other will not be called, that is short-cuirciting

Comment: @idclev463035818 Wow, I didn't think like that! I hope someone will come up with a solution that doesn't have such drawbacks.

Comment: i makes no difference for your `fun` example, but it is an argument against using such function in general and maybe part of the reason you didn't find something like this in C++ (but in python)

Comment: @ArdentCoder there is no (simple) way to avoid that. You need the parameters before you can call a function

Comment: @idclev463035818: or parameter should be generator/callable. but more verbose in simple case.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah I thought about that, but this again introduces overhead and indeed obfuscated the call-site. I am still in favour for a simple `if-else`. I have been trhough a phase of writing helpers for each an everything, but there is no need to invent something when a language construct (`if-else`) already does the job